# How does MakeBoxes handle an n-ary operator?

Tags: formatting

I want to format results from `Reduce` using the $\cup$ symbol instead of the $\lor$ symbol. For example, `Reduce[x^2 > 4, x, Reals]` produces $x<-2\lor x>2$ while I would like it to produce $x<-2\cup x>2$.

My current solution is to add the head `xO` to use in place of the `Or` head and associate the appropriate formatting with the `xO` head using `MakeBoxes`.

```
xO /: MakeBoxes[xO[x_, y_], form_] :=                                                             
    RowBox[{MakeBoxes[x, form], "\[Union]", MakeBoxes[y, form]}];
```

When I want to invoke the special formatting, I simply substitute `xO` for `Or`.

```
Reduce[x^2 > 4, x, Reals] /. Or -> xO
```

This produces the desired result of $(x<-2)\cup (x>2)$. I am feeling like a master bit-twiddler at this point.

Of course, my next test case didn't work.

```
Reduce[x^3 + 2 x^2 - x - 2 == 0] /. Or -> xO
(* xO(x==-2,x==-1,x==1) *)
```

My `MakeBoxes[xO[x_, y_]]` definition above does not match the case when `xO` has three arguments. I added the following to limp along a little further.

```
xO /: MakeBoxes[xO[x_, y_, z_], form_] :=                                                         
    RowBox[{MakeBoxes[x, form], "\[Union]", MakeBoxes[y, form], "\[Union]", MakeBoxes[z, form]}];
```

This works for three arguments, but is clearly not a robust solution. What is the general method for an n-ary function?

I tried several variations of the following:

```
xO /: MakeBoxes[xO[x_, y__], form_] :=                                                            
    RowBox[{MakeBoxes[x, form], "\[Union]", MakeBoxes[y, form]}];
```

which produced the error:

```
MakeBoxes::argt: "MakeBoxes called with 3 arguments; 1 or 2 arguments are expected"
```

when applied to the `Reduce[x^3 + 2 x^2 - x - 2 == 0] /. Or -> xO` test case.

I am probably missing something obvious. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were almost there. You just need to use the multiple-argument pattern, and generalize your code accordingly to create the internals of `RowBox` programmatically:

```
xO /: MakeBoxes[xO[x___], form_] :=
  RowBox[
    Riffle[
      Map[MakeBoxes[#, form] &, {x}],
      "\[Union]"
    ]
  ]
```

Note however that the above implementation leaks evaluation. It may or may not be a problem, but for example here:

```
x = 1;
xO[x == 1, x > 1, x < 1]
```

one may argue that the desired result should not be sensitive to the possible global values that `x` may have, so the result:

```
(* True \[Union] False \[Union] False *)
```

may be unsatisfacory. Thus, here is a more careful version:

```
ClearAll[xO];
SetAttributes[xO, HoldAllComplete]; 
xO /: MakeBoxes[xO[x___], form_] :=
  RowBox@Riffle[
     List @@ Replace[
       HoldComplete[x],
       elem_ :> With[{eval = MakeBoxes[elem, form]}, eval /; True],
       {1}
     ],
     "\[Union]"
  ]
```

which now gives

```
xO[x == 1, x > 1, x < 1]

(* x == 1 \[Union] x > 1 \[Union] x < 1 *)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but it would have taken me an long and indeterminate amount of time to come to that solution. Thank you @Leonid.

Comment: @RandomBits Glad I could help. See also my update on evaluation leaks and the second version. Thanks for the accept. B.t.w., typically it is better to wait for a while before accepting an answer, to encourage others to contribute more answers. You can also accept a different answer at any time later.

Comment: I understand the use of `SetAttributes[xO, HoldAllComplete]`, but I am having trouble understanding the details of the rule inside of `Replace`. It looks like the gist of it is that you are safely evaluating MakeBox for each argument of xO.

Comment: @RandomBits I should have given more explanations. I need to  pass each of the arguments of the `x` sequence to `MakeBoxes`. I use `HoldComplete` to avoid their premature evaluation. To evaluate them inside `HoldComplete`, I use [Trott-Strzebonski technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633236/replace-inside-held-expression/6633334#6633334). This is actually an overkill here, I could have just used  `elem_ :> MakeBoxes[elem, form]`, and then all these would evaluate at the point when `HoldComplete` head is changed into `List`.

Comment: @RandomBits In other words, `List @@ Replace[ HoldComplete[x], elem_ :> MakeBoxes[elem, form], {1}]` should work just as well here, while being less magical.

Comment: This is working great. I have a similar function to replace power: `xPower /: MakeBoxes[xPower[x_, y_ /; y < 0], form_] := SuperscriptBox[MakeBoxes[x, form], MakeBoxes[y, form]];`. This keeps Mathematica from inverting negative integer exponents. Do I need to do anything to protect x and y in this case? And would it be something like this: `HoldComplete[x] /. HoldComplete[elem_] :> MakeBoxes[elem, form]`?

Comment: @RandomBits No, in this case you don't need this, since you explicitly place `x` and `y` into `MakeBoxes`. We needed it in the case of `xO`, since we had a variable number of arguments, and we needed to protect those from early evaluation during our manipulations. In this case, this programmatic manipulation stage is absent. You may want to make `xPower` `HoldAll` or `HoldAllComplete` though.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the internal typesetting function `` BoxForm`MakeInfixForm `` for this purpose:

```
xO /: MakeBoxes[xO[a__], form_] := RowBox[BoxForm`MakeInfixForm[Or[a], "\[Union]", form]]
```

The key feature is that parenthesization of the arguments is controlled by the precedence of the head of the first argument, in this case [`Or`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or). Then:

```
xO[x == 1, x > 1, x < 1]
```

> ```
> x == 1 \[Union] x > 1 \[Union] x < 1
> ```

If you want parenthesization of the arguments to be based on the precedence of [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times) instead of [`Or`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or), you would do:

```
xO /: MakeBoxes[xO[a__], form_] := RowBox[BoxForm`MakeInfixForm[Times[a], "\[Union]", form]]

xO[x == 1, x > 1, x < 1]
```

> ```
> (x == 1) \[Union] (x > 1) \[Union] (x < 1)
> ```